# How to delete item in Bin "... cannot be modified or deleted because it is required by MacOS"?

Tags: mojave, trash

I'm on a 2014 MacBook Air, 10.14.5

A couple of weeks ago I did a quick sweep of my files and drives to get rid of junk, mostly old photos and videos I had accumulated that I didn't need/want anymore. Everything deleted fine, except for one .mp4 file. This file, it seems, managed to get into my Bin, but is now stuck. I would really like to get rid of it - it was copied off an old USB drive and is about 5GB, which is a lot when you only have 10GB free space.

When I drag it anywhere, it just copies. When the bin is emptied, I get the message "....mp4 can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS".

I've looked for possible solutions, including turning off System Integrity Protection and reinstalling the OS but to no avail.
Please help! Sorry if I've missed any details

Comment: What do you mean by Bin - macOS does not have one - it does have Trash

Comment: @Mark I think you'll find it is called Bin

Comment: my macOS 10.14.5 says Empty Trash on Finder Menu. The directory in your home is ~/.Trash there is also .Trashes on the root of every volume. But no bin

Comment: Regardless, the problem exists.

Comment: Yes but we cannot understand it as bin is not on macOS so we need more info like a screen shot showing the error

Comment: @Mark I apologise for the confusion. It is "bin" everywhere on my device so I presumed it was similar everywhere.

Comment: @SteveChambers As stated in the question, I did attempt that, but unfortunately it seems it is not connected to the SIP

Comment: I'm guessing that by `Bin` he means `/bin`

Comment: @GEdgar, The phrase he uses, "When the bin is emptied,..." is the giveaway expression and I'd say based on the context he's referring to Trash as in a Trash Bin not the, hidden by default,  `/bin` directory.

Comment: I think they call it the Trash in North-America but they use the word Bin for the UK (as in the trash bin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '**“…” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS.**' message is typically caused by **ACL** permissions set on the file which cannot be changed unless **SIP** is disabled. Obviously a 5GB .mp4 file is not system file that needs protection and has somehow may have had erroneous **ACL** permissions set on it.

One sure way of deleting this file without having to disable **SIP** or modify **ACL** permissions is to boot to  **Recovery Mode**, (**⌘R** when restarting the **Mac**), and then in **Terminal** (on the **Utilities** menu)... use the following *command*, e.g.:

```
rm -f /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_Short_Name/.Trash/filename.mp4
```

- The example *command* above assumes the main **Startup** volume is **Macintosh HD**, change as needed.
- The **Your_Short_Name** is that which you normally see in **Finder** as the name on your **Home** folder.
- If `filename.mp4` has spaces in it, then escape with backslashes as shown in the example *command*.

Then type `reboot` and press **enter** to restart the **Mac** back to normal mode boot.

---

- **ACL** - [Access Control Lists](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/access_control_lists) See also the `chmod` manual page.
- **SIP** - [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)